# My Hexadecimal to Binary Converter nulls if enters a lowercase

Tags: java, binary, hex, converters

im a new (not totally new) in java 
so I have a program to work that converts Hexadecimal to binary
So the output should like this :

if user input : 200F:
"The output should like this:"
2- 0010
0- 0000
0- 0000
F- 1111

but the problem is if the user inputs a lowercase letter it displays null
check out my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
        HashMap<Character, String> map = new HashMap<Character, String>();
        map.put('0', "0000");
        map.put('1', "0001");
        map.put('2', "0010");            
        map.put('3', "0011");
        map.put('4', "0100");
        map.put('5', "0101");
        map.put('6', "0110");
        map.put('7', "0111");
        map.put('8', "1000");
        map.put('9', "1001");
        map.put('A', "1010");
        map.put('B', "1011");
        map.put('C', "1100");
        map.put('D', "1101");
        map.put('F', "1111");
        System.out.print("Input your Hex Number here : ");
        String userInput = input.readLine();
        String resultx = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
            /* used for separating the value */
            char hexVal = userInput.charAt(i);
            String binary = map.get(hexVal);
            resultx=resultx +"\n" + hexVal + "-" + binary;

        }

        //Main output
        System.out.println("The Binary of " + userInput + ":" + "\n"  + resultx);


    }
}
```

I think i can also create a hashmap that contains the lowercase letter but i think my code is getting ugly if i do that..

So can u help me how to ignore the case in my code?

I also created another program which i used arrays but someone told me that it has an ugly structures and it not efficient and accurate.. they also said that i was in a complicated one so they gave me an idea in using hashmap and built in converter . but the hashmap looks fine..

Check out my other code: and tell me which is better among the two because when i'm running this program, it's run good and no problem. so just check it out:

[my code](http://ideone.com/jHWFBa)

thank you . i hope you will solve my problem..

Comment: Just call the method `.toUpperCase()` on your chars.

Comment: Why not use `Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(userInput, 16));`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch
ya but that is pretty much better than this?

Comment: It's certainly a lot shorter, and Oracle has already debugged it.

Comment: ahh okay! I already created a program like that. check out my code:
but the problem is its only display 3 digits if i type 0:

check my code here:

http://ideone.com/nPCkez

Comment: @JasperVanzRecitas You can't change the class name, otheriwse it doesn't know which one to run. Use the one it gives you.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your user input string to upper case before processing.

```
System.out.print("Input your Hex Number here : ");
String userInput = input.readLine();
userInput = userInput.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 1):

`String binary = map.get(Character.toUpperCase(hexVal));` can also solve the problem.